# Approach to store cookies in Angular and Java

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, cookies

I'm developing a web application using **Angular** for **client-side** and Java with **Spring** on **server-side**. I have read some articles, but haven't found concrete answers to my questions. The goal is **store, read and modify cookies** from both sides. I want to figure out handy and simple approach to store and read cookies.

**First of all**, are there some best practises/conventions to setting it on client-side, and then if it's needed read and modify on both sides or...?

I found that on client-side it's pretty easy using **ngx-cookie-service**. And with server-side it's worse. I have tried to add cookie in response in that way:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String hello(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("foo", "bar"));
    //..        
}
```

But it doesn't store a cookie.

Also using Spring I have tried to read already stored cookie by client-side, but it also doesn't work:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello(@CookieValue("myCookie") String cookie){
     log.info("My cookie {}", cookie);
     (...)
}
```

Comment: Do you use an Angular service with an XHR to a different origin? (URL is different than the page Source)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client side its easy with various npm packages such as the one you mentioned.

Server side, you would typically use the "Set-Cookie" response header to set a cookie in the browser. This is typically done for authentication purposes on the /api/login endpoint response but you could use it for other purposes.

When using the Set-Cookie response header, it is good practice to make it HttpOnly which prevents JavaScript from accessing and tampering. It is simply sent in all subsequent API requests and JavaScript need not even worry about it.

This could be used, server-side, for example, when receiving an incoming request, to determine who the authenticated user is. And if not, give em a 401.

Secure means the cookie can only be passed over HTTPS protocol.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Not sure how you would code Java Spring to set the Set-Cookie response header, but I'm sure you can look that one up.

Edit:
[response_headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InNhe.png)

[empty_cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnXXi.png)

Comment: HI danday74, thanks for your answer. Could you please check screenshots in your edited answer and help me to figure out this behavior? In headers there is "Set-Cookie" header. But cookies storage is empty. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure, after the browser receives the Set-Cookie response, try making an HTTP request to the same domain that sent the Set-Cookie response from the same browser and see if the cookie is included in the HTTP request headers. Also, it might be because its HttpOnly?

Comment: I've found the possibility to set cookie's HttpOnly flag. Both options(true/false) didn't work for my case.

Answer (score 2):

check this: [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

Basically if your server has this setting in the header then your request to the server also has to have the withCredentials prop set to true